# Google Glass USB driver installation, "This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object"

Tags: android, sdk, usb, adb, google-glass

I am trying to get ADB on my computer running 64bit Windows 7 to recognize Google Glass.

- I have read many tutorials online, and believe I have followed all steps correctly.
- I have the SDK installed.
- I have the USB drivers installed, and then I go to Device Manager and point Glass 1 at the location of my USB drivers inside `\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

It gives me the error

> This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object

I also tried going into `android_winusb.inf` and adding the following

```
;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

As these are the values I found when looked under Hardware IDs for my Google Glass.

I have also tried many variations of the above, but I always get the exact same error; "This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object."

I am logged in as administrator.

Any help at all would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to disable driver verification, check this out:

http://tivadj-tech.blogspot.com/2012/09/certificate-check-error-when-installing.html

This is a troublesome part of Glass development, but once it works, it works!  It will get easier.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. I still get the same issue. I followed these instructions as I am on Windows 7:
http://sabrent.com/support/knowledgebase.php?article=14

Comment: That's frustrating, did you get the same error?  Do you have any anti-virus software installed?  You know that once the driver does work you have to approve the computer on Glass itself right?  I'm not sure you are to that step yet, but that is new as of XE16, and trips some folks up.  Sounds like you are doing everything right to me.